# Nested Relative and Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to layouts in android and would like to implement a layout like the one shown below however I am a bit confused as to how I should layer my layouts in XML.

[image]

I am currently trying a:

```
<LinearLayout>
     <RelativeLayout>
         <ImageView>
         <TextView>
     </RelativeLayout>
     <LinearLayout>
         <ImageView>
         <TextView>
         <ImageView>
         <TextView>
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't want to over complicate my layout structure. Would there be a better way to structure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be best to have a look at this link. As a rule of thumb, don't try and nest layouts too much, i.e. keep them as shallow as possible.

So relative layouts are usually better in this case.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html